# How do you groupby and count array frequency in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe cointaining the following values below.

```
                         dt    mentions    hod
0 2022-02-16 10:15:42+00:00        [$X]     10
1 2022-02-16 10:13:13+00:00        [$X]     10
2 2022-02-15 13:41:07+00:00        [$Y]     13
3 2022-02-15 13:27:25+00:00    [$Z, $Y]     13
4 2022-02-15 13:15:52+00:00        [$Z]     13
```

I am running a groupby for the hour of day `hod_group = df.groupby(['hod'])`

However, I am having trouble figuring out how do I get into this format after a groupby.

```
         mentions     hod
{"$X": 2}             10
{"$Y": 2, "$Z", 2}    13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `explode` the data, then `value_counts` per group:

```
(df.explode('mentions')
   .groupby('hod')['mentions']
   .agg(lambda s: s.value_counts().to_dict())
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
   hod            mentions
0   10           {'$X': 2}
1   13  {'$Y': 2, '$Z': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Flatten values by [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and then count by [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) per groups in lambda function:

```
from collections import Counter
from  itertools import chain

f = lambda x: Counter(chain.from_iterable(x))
hod_group = df.groupby('hod')['mentions'].agg(f).reset_index(name='mentioned')
print (hod_group)
   hod           mentioned
0   10           {'$X': 2}
1   13  {'$Y': 2, '$Z': 2}
```

Comment: I tried `df.explode('mentions')`, which does not work here to split the 'mention' records? Why?